# Hierarchical display of DB data in ASP.NET MVC c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to obtain information from multiple tables and display the data in a hierarchical view.  I have the following tables:

- TRACK_INFO
- GEN_ED_HEAD
- GEN_ED_SUB_HEAD
- GEN_ED_SUB_SUB_HEAD
- GEN_ED_COURSE
- CORE_HEAD
- CORE_SUB_HEAD
- CORE_SUB_SUB_HEAD
- CORE_COURSE

I need to first display one record from TRACK INFO, then display each record of GEN_ED_HEAD with each GEN_ED_SUB_HEAD listed under the respective head and then GEN_ED_SUB_SUB_HEAD listed under that and finally the GEN_ED_COURSE listed.

I know how to do this but not in MVC.  Here is an example of the looping (hierarchy) i am looking for:

```
Foreach(track in TRACK_INFO)
{
   display track info
   foreach(genEdHead in GEN_ED_HEAD)
   { 
       display GEN_ED_HEAD info
       foreach(henEdSubHead in GEN_ED_SUB_HEAD)
       {
           display gen ed sub head info
           foreach (genEdSubSubHead in GEN_ED_SUB_SUB_HEAD)
           {
               display gen ed sub sub head info
               foreach(course in GEN_ED_COURSE)
               {
                  display gen ed course info
                }
            }
         }
     }
   }
```

Comment: Not clear what you asking. Do you want to display the data in a view like a treeview? You should post you view model, controller and view